# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError in HDFView

Tags: java, hdf5

Whenever HDFView opens an hdf file which is created by a user or by an application, it shows the following error (I am using Red Hat linux).

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /dwr2/com/lib/libjhdf.so: /lib/tls/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.4' not found (required by /dwr2/com/lib/libjhdf.so)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at ncsa.hdf.hdflib.HDFLibrary.<clinit>(HDFLibrary.java:245)
    at ncsa.hdf.object.h4.H4File.isThisType(H4File.java:170)
    at ncsa.hdf.view.DefaultTreeView.openFile(DefaultTreeView.java:1328)
    at ncsa.hdf.view.HDFView.actionPerformed(HDFView.java:1016)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Sour ce)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing a SO file, perhaps you have the wrong binary or a broken symlink, also take a look at: http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/support/help/MailArchives/gempak/msg05278.html

This might be related to your problem.